# Jasmine - testing data typed into input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

**BACKGROUND**

I have a simple function which does not allow numbers to be typed in an input field:

```
rejectCharacterIfNumeric: function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    key = String.fromCharCode(key);
    var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
    if (regex.test(key)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
},
```

I call the function as follows:

```
$("#testNumerics").keypress(function(e){ qqw.validate.rejectCharacterIfNumeric(e); } );
```

**CHALLENGE**

I have a jasmine test to simulate input entry and am expecting the input to ignore numbers ([I'm using autotype plug-in to simulate input](https://github.com/mmonteleone/jquery.autotype))

```
describe("check only letters allowed in field", function(){

    var originalTimeout;

    it("it should have letters and no numbers", function(done){

        var fixture = readFixtures('name.html');
        setFixtures(fixture);

        // don't allow numbers in first or last name fields
        $("#testNumerics").keypress(function(e){ qqw.validate.rejectCharacterIfNumeric(e); } );

        $('#testNumerics').autotype('He66', {delay: 200}); // autotype with delay so can see it in action

        setTimeout(function() {
            expect($("#testNumerics").val().length).toEqual(2); //
            done();
        }, 1800);

    });

});
```

**THE PROBLEM**

Jasmine result:

```
Expected 4 to equal 2.
```

The problem is that the `rejectCharacterIfNumeric(e)` function does not seem to work on fixtures, although if I add in a `console.log()` I know for a fact that the function is being called correctly by the test.

**QUESTION**

Is there a better way to simulate input into a text input that would make the function behave as it does in the real world?

Comment: u talking about E2E using protractor

Comment: No, I'm using Jasmine